# Laravel: How to fire event when a particular column in users table changes?

Tags: php, laravel, events, notifications, eloquent

In my users table I have a column with the name verified and data type boolean with default value 'false', However, I want to fire an event when that column value to any particular user changes to 'true', So i can make a notification based on that event?
Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add a hook to the model event and perform a check. The code below goes in your model. You may or may not want to pass the user object with the event. This might come in handy if you're sending notifications.

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::updated(function($user) {
        if ($user->verified == true) {
            event(new UserVerified($user));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be a good way to implement this idea, However I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it. Thank you again.

Comment: This is the only way you can detect changes to your model data. The same can be implemented using observers, which does the same but the logic gets moved to another class. Another way would to be detect and fire the event in your controller when you update. But this becomes tedious when you update the model in multiple locations.

Answer (score 0):

What I am thinking of is to create a trigger on update of your target table.  Upon update, you can insert a record into another table `EVENT`.

Your code can be periodically polling from that the `EVENT` table to process these updates.

If you are using Oracle DB, [Oracle queues](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96587/qintro.htm) will be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Attribute Events package to fire events when a model attribute changes: https://github.com/jpkleemans/attribute-events

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $dispatchesEvents = [
        'verified:true' => UserVerified::class,
    ];
}
```